# Need to Save Relationship in MongoDB with Rails and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need  to save `group_id` in my user document using Rails collection_select
Code Listed Below

Model User:

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps
 include Amistad::FriendModel

 field :name, :type => String
 field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
 field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""

#relations
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :group
```

Model Group

```
 class Group
   include Mongoid::Document
   attr_accessible :name, :degree
   field :name, type: String
   field :degree, type: String
   has_many :users
```

and generated form :

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.collection_select :group_id,  Group.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<%end%>
```

this would save the user document and not save the group_id mention in collection_select, any idea

Comment: Could you paste the code that saves the user?

Comment: @JhonCortes what u r controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a better way but it worked

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.school_id = current_user.school_id
@user.group_id = params[:user][:group_id]
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Subject was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @subject }
  else
    format.html { render  "new" }
    format.json { render json: @subject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Do you use User.new when creating new user or Group.user.create. Latter should work.

Comment: ye i use User.new in my controler ' user = User.new(params[:user])
    user.school_id = current_user.school_id
    user.save'

Comment: Then you should use group.user.create

Comment: this is a way but a i will have other request :thks